# su does not change everything to other user (cgroups)

Tags: ssh, systemd, su

If I run this command:

```
su -l otheruser -c 'strace /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user 2> /tmp/su.err'
```

It fails:

> Failed to create root cgroup hierarchy: Permission denied
>
> Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied

I see in the strace output that starting systemd as user failed here:

```
mkdir("/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user/root/754/systemd-3893", 0755) = -1 
     EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Where does /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user/**root**/ come from?

If I run the same command via ssh to localhost it works:

```
ssh otheruser@localhost 'strace /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user 2> /tmp/ssh.err'
```

Here, the right directory gets used:

```
mkdir("/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user/modwork_gew_dfj/825/systemd-4272", 0755) = 0
```

Why does it work via ssh, but not via su?

Version: su (GNU coreutils) 8.17

## Update

Here you can see that the cgroup does not get changed by my version of `su`:

```
host:~ # su -l otheruser
otheruser@host:~$ cat /proc/$PPID/cgroup
10:hugetlb:/
9:perf_event:/
8:blkio:/
7:net_cls:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpuacct,cpu:/
2:cpuset:/
1:name=systemd:/user/root/5913 <################ root
```

Via `ssh`:

```
host:~ # ssh otheruser@host
otheruser@host:~$ cat /proc/$PPID/cgroup
10:hugetlb:/
9:perf_event:/
8:blkio:/
7:net_cls:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpuacct,cpu:/
2:cpuset:/
1:name=systemd:/user/otheruser/5919 <################ otheruser
```

## Update2

My version of `su` does not change the cgroup (See the link in the answer of user "ax."). Is there a way to change the cgroup (before or after) calling `su`?

## Update3

This version does not have this issue: `su util-linux 2.25`

Comment: Just asking....Your root account has a password, right?

Comment: what systemd version do you have?

Comment: Is it a bug or a feature, that `su` does not change the cgroup? What do the gnu coreutils people say?

Comment: Try `su -` to completely reset your environment and get a new login shell for root.  (You can also do this with specific users as e.g. `su - guettli`)

Comment: @AdamKatz AFAIK `su -l guettli` does the same as `su - guettli`.

Comment: Yes it does.  My bad, I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`su` inherits its `cgroup` from the originating session](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Systemd-Own-su-Command), not from the user passed to `su`. So when you call `su -l otheruser -c systemd ...` as root, `systemd` tries to use the root cgroup (`/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user/root/...`) as `otheruser` and fails.

With `ssh otheruser@localhost ...`, both user and cgroup are `otheruser`, and everything works as expected.

Comment: For me this looks like `su` is doing something wrong. With `su -l` the cgroup should be changed. Is there a way to change the cgroup? I would like to avoid "ssh to localhost".

Comment: Please read the link in my answer (and the systemd issues it links to). Exactly because su behaves inconsistently, the systemd developers added the new command "machinectl shell", which should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, `"machinectl` could work. Unfortunately I need to support an old system where this command is not available. Is there a way to use `cgexec` (or other tool) in combination with `su` to get this working (without ssh)?

Comment: I am not aware of any other tool that does what you want. [Neither is the systemd lead developer](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/825#issuecomment-127957710) - hence the creation of "[machinectl shell](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machinectl.html#shell%20[[NAME@]NAME%20[PATH%20[ARGUMENTS...]]])".

Comment: Reading the ["machinectl shell" man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machinectl.html#shell%20%5B%5BNAME@%5DNAME%20%5BPATH%20%5BARGUMENTS...%5D%5D%5D%20) I noticed this: _Note that systemd-run(1) may be used in place of the shell command, and allows more detailed, low-level configuration of the invoked unit. However, it is frequently more privileged than the shell command._ Might this be an option for you?

Comment: damm, even `systemd-run` does not exist on this old platform. I am sorry. Unfortunately I need to support this old platform ... Thanks for efforts!

Comment: ax,guettli: any more progress to this problem? I am supporting this older system sudo and execute command in another username. This works in rhel 6.x with cgred, but now in rhel 7.2 systemd, the command cannot be under the cgroup of otheruser.slice without ssh otheruser@localhost

Answer (score 0):

as guettli pointed out su don't work anymore.
in centos7.2 as root I tried this seems to work for cgroup by uid:
Assume you have uid=1000 that is a high cpu share user and uid=1001 that is a low cpu share user, (I am guessing by default every new user is getting a share of 1024 which will be the case for root user (uid=0))

in centos7.2 as root I tried this seems to work for cgroup:

```
systemd-run --uid=1000 --slice=user-1000.slice do_uid_1000_work_commands
systemd-run --uid=1001 --slice=user-1001.slice do_uid_1001_work_commands
```

the above will create two adhoc services with the corresponding user-slice config under /run/systemd/system/:

```
/run/systemd/system/*10345*

/run/systemd/system/run-10345.service

/run/systemd/system/run-10345.service.d:
```

50-Description.conf  50-ExecStart.conf  50-Slice.conf  50-User.conf

Here are the rest of my configurations:
--> /etc/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/50-CPUShares.conf

```
[Slice]
CPUShares=4096
```

--> /etc/systemd/system/user-1001.slice.d/50-CPUShares.conf

```
[Slice]
CPUShares=1024
```

--> /usr/lib/systemd/system/user-1001.slice

```
[Unit]
Description=User and Session Slice for uid = 1001 (low cpu share user)
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Before=slices.target

[Service]
Slice=user-1001
CPUShares=1024
```

--> /usr/lib/systemd/system/user-1000.slice

```
[Unit]
Description=User and Session Slice for uid = 1000 (high cpu share user)
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Before=slices.target

[Service]
Slice=user-1000
CPUShares=4096
```